# Give an opaque color to inner base of otherwise transparent cube?

Tags: unreal-4, materials

This is my first time using a material in Unreal Engine. I am trying to create a transparent cube except for the inner face of the base, which I would like to be opaque white, like in this drawing:

[image: cube with transparent sides and an opaque white inner base]

I have created a cube with transparent sides and an opaque white top:

[image: blueprint of a cube with transparent sides and an opaque white top]

I am attempting to paint the top face with a semi-transparent blue, like the sides, and move the upward-facing painting of that face down to the base, but that is not going well:

[image: blueprint produing a cube with transparent sides and an opaque blue top]

How might I achieve this material? I am using the material on glTF cubes in 3dtiles. They accept materials in the same way as a static mesh does, but it is not possible to identify the vertices.

Comment: Could you explain what does "gtTF cubes in 3d tiles" means?

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix could be creating two different material slots with two different domains. To create two different materials slots you have to go in your 3d software of  choice. In this way you can have your opaque face with the default material domain:

[image: Example of opaque material]

I set the "two sided" option to true because as I understood you want to see the opaque face from every angle.
For the other faces you could have the material set to translucent in this way:

[image: Example of translucent material]

Don't mind the nodes or the other stuff.
In the end you should have something that look like this:

[image]

With a few tweaks you should achieve exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I am restricted to one mesh. I can't use two material slots.

Comment: You can have multiple material slots on the same mesh